# c# mvvm bind views to tabcontrol with header

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, tabcontrol

I have a wpf programme with a main View (`Window`)which contains a `TabControl` to show several different `UserControl` Views (the *sub-views*, one in each tab).  Every View has an associated ViewModel.

I wish to bind the `TabControl` so that I just need to load a new *sub-view* into the ApplicationViewModel and it will appear on the `TabControl`.

I have successfully bound the *sub-views* to the content, but cannot seem to get anything in the header.  I wish to bind the header to a property in the *sub-view*'s ViewModel, specifically `TabTitle`.

Application View (`DataTemplate` binding not working):

```
<Window ...>
    <DockPanel>
        <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding PageViews}" SelectedIndex="0"> <!--Working-->
            <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding DataContext.TabTitle}, Path=DataContext.TabTitle}" /> <!--Not Working-->
                </DataTemplate>    
            </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        </TabControl>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Application ViewModel (`ObservableObject` basically implements INotifyPropertyChanged`):

```
class ApplicationViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    private DataManager Data;
    private ObservableCollection<UserControl> _pageViews;

    internal ApplicationViewModel()
    {
        Data = new DataManager();
        PageViews.Add(new Views.MembersView(new MembersViewModel(Data.DataSet)));
    }

    public ObservableCollection<UserControl> PageViews
    {
        get
        {
            if (_pageViews == null)
            {
                _pageViews = new ObservableCollection<UserControl>();
            }
            return _pageViews;
        }
    }
```

The MembersView Code behind:

```
public partial class MembersView : UserControl
{
    public MembersView(MembersViewModel ViewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = ViewModel;
    }
}
```

MembersViewModel (truncated):

```
public class MembersViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public TabTitle { get; protected set; }

    public MembersViewModel(DataSet BBDataSet)
    {
        TabTitle = "Members";
    }

    //All view properties
}
```

I'm sure that it is something simple...

Comment: You should not create `ObservableCollection<UserControl>` but `ObservableCollection<MembersViewModel>` and `ItemTemplate`/`ContentTemplate` should be `MembersView`

Comment: How do I tell the programme that a view needs to be displayed?

Comment: if you would bind to `ObservableCollection<MembersViewModel>` then `DataContext` of each header and content would be an instance of `MembersViewModel` and it would be converted to UI element with `DataTemplate` (`ItemTemplate` for header and `ContentTemplate` for content) so your `TextBlock` in the header would look like `<TextBlock ... Text="{Binding TabTitle}"/>` and `ContentTemplate` would be - I assume - `MembersView` that display _All view properties_ in the same way as in the header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are binding the TabControl to a collection of type UserControl. That means the data context for each item will be of type UserControl. There is no property named "TabTitle" in UserControl, so the binding will not work.

I think what you are trying to do can be accomplished with the following changes:

1. Have ApplicationViewModel expose a collection of type MembersViewModel, instead of UserControl, and populate it appropriately.
2. Setup a ContentTemplate to create views for your items in the TabControl:

   ```
   <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
       <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type namespace:MembersViewModel}">
           <namespace:MembersView />
       </DataTemplate>
   </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
   ```

   (Replace "namespace:" with your xaml imported namespace containing your controls.)
3. Update the ItemTemplate in your TabControl so it binds properly to the view model:

   ```
   <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding TabTitle}}" />
       </DataTemplate>    
   </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
   ```
4. Update MembersView to have a parameterless constructor. The DataContext on the view will be set for you by the TabControl. If you need to access the view model from your code-behind, it should be available through the DataContext property after the InitializeComponent() call.

Anytime you are working with ItemsControl (and its extensions such as ListBox, TreeView, TabControl, etc.), you should never be instantiating your own item views. You always want to setup a template that instantiates the view based on the data (or view model) and bind directly to the data (or view model) in the ItemsSource property. This allows all of the item's data contexts to be setup for you so you can bind to them.

Edit: Since you have multiple view / viewmodel pairings, you will want to define your templates slightly differently:

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding PageViews}" SelectedIndex="0">
    <TabControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type namespace:MembersViewModel}">
            <namespace:MembersView />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type namespace:ClassesViewModel}">
            <namespace:ClassesView />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type namespace:SessionsViewModel}">
            <namespace:SessionsView />
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.Resources>
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding TabTitle}}" />
        </DataTemplate>    
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

The difference is that you want to define multiple data templates, one for each type, in your resources. That means it will use those templates each time it encounters those types. You still want to set ItemTemplate to force the tab headers to use a specific template. However, do not set ContentTemplate, allowing the content to use the data templates defined in resources.

I hope that makes sense.

P.S. You can also define these data templates in a higher level resource dictionary, such as in your main window or your application, if you want them to apply to content presenters every place you use those view models, rather than only in this one `TabControl`.

Comment: Ok, so I have now got (in ApplicationView): `<DockPanel> <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding PageViewModels}" SelectedIndex="0"> <TabControl.ContentTemplate> <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:TabbedViewModelBase}">  <views:MembersView />  </DataTemplate> </TabControl.ContentTemplate> <TabControl.ItemTemplate> <DataTemplate> <Label Content="{Binding TabTitle}" /> </DataTemplate> </TabControl.ItemTemplate>`. This shows the View for the first tab ok (`MemberView`), How do I set the Views for each tab without having to define them individually?(`PageViewModels` returns a collection of VMs)

Comment: There must be something I am missing with how your classes are setup. What is the `TabbedViewModelBase` type you specified in the content template? I thought the type was `MembersViewModel`. It is hard to answer your question with only a partial understanding of what you are doing.

Comment: `ApplicationViewModel` and `ApplicationView` are the main app.  At the moment, `ApplicationView` just holds a `TabControl`. I wish that each tab contains a _sub-view_ (`MemberView`, `ClassesView`, `SessionsView`), each of these has an associated ViewModel (`MemberViewModel` etc.).  Inorder to have a collection of these _sub-view models_, each one extends `TabbedViewModelBase` (this just implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and defines a `TabTitle` property). `ApplicationViewModel` now presents a `ObservableCollection<TabbedViewModelBase> PageViews` for the `TabControl` to bind to

Comment: Ok, now I understand. So you have three different view / viewmodel pairings. Because of that, we need to define the content templates slightly differently. I updated my answer.